# Unable to call Javascript function onload a asp:button using ASP.NET4

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am unable to call a Javascript function on the OnLoad event of a asp:button

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; "   onLoad = "AllHide()"  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()"  />
```

Javascript

```
  function AllHide() {
        alert("Hello");
  }
```

Please Help

Comment: i am trying to hide asp:button without using CSS or serverside Coding. How can i hide this control on loading and thanks for your response.

Comment: See below, you'll need to start the control as hidden with the `style` property. While this is CSS still, you'll be able to control it directly with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to toggle styles like you are trying

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=""  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()" style="display:none;visiblity:hidden;" />
```

**Original Comment** You can't do `onLoad` with JavaScript for any button. What are you hoping to accomplish? We can help figure out that solution.

Comment: i am trying to hide asp:button without using CSS or serverside Coding. How can i hide this control on loading and thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks alot again Kirk   the style worked       visible = Flase wont work because then i cant retreive it back from Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Here's why. The OnLoad event in ASP.NET for a control is fired while the server is building the page (on the web server), but before it sends it to the browser (running on the user's machine).

Code on the web server can't directly call code on the browser computer (which hasn't even got the page yet).

If you just want to hide the control, just do this in your markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; "  visible="false"  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()"  />
```

Another approach (hidden control doesn't takes up space):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; "  style="display:none;"  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()"  />
```

Another approach (hidden control takes up space)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; "  style="visibility:hidden;"  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()"  />
```

Comment: if i set visible = false then javascript will not make it visible again

Comment: Then just set it as a style on the element instead. Hold on, adding an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the page level. The page has a javascript onload event.